# Swagger schema properties ignored when using $ref - why?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to build a Swagger model for a time interval, using a simple string to store the time (I know that there is also datetime):

```
definitions:
  Time:
    type: string
    description: Time in 24 hour format "hh:mm".
  TimeInterval:
    type: object
    properties:
      lowerBound:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Time"
        description: Lower bound on the time interval.
        default: "00:00"
      upperBound:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Time"
        description: Upper bound on the time interval.
        default: "24:00"
```

For some reason the generated HTML does not show the lowerBound and upperBound "description", but only the original Time "description". This makes me think I'm not doing this correctly.

So the question is if using a model as a type can in fact be done as I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

TL;DR: `$ref` siblings are supported (to an extent) in OpenAPI 3.1. In previous OpenAPI versions, any keywords alongside `$ref` are ignored.

#### OpenAPI 3.1

Your definition will work as expected when migrated to OpenAPI 3.1. This new version is fully compatible with JSON Schema 2020-12, which allows `$ref` siblings *in schemas*.

```yaml
openapi: 3.1.0
...

components:
  schemas:
    Time:
      type: string
      description: Time in 24 hour format "hh:mm".

    TimeInterval:
      type: object
      properties:
        lowerBound:
          # ------- This will work in OAS 3.1 ------- #
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/Time"
          description: Lower bound on the time interval.
          default: "00:00"
        upperBound:
          # ------- This will work in OAS 3.1 ------- #
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/Time"
          description: Upper bound on the time interval.
          default: "24:00"
```

*Outside of schemas* - for example, in responses or parameters - $refs only allow sibling `summary` and `description` keywords. Any other keywords alongside these $refs will be ignored.

```yaml
# openapi: 3.1.0

# This is supported
parameters:
  - $ref: '#/components/parameters/id'
    description: Entity ID

# This is NOT supported
parameters:
  - $ref: '#/components/parameters/id'
    required: true
```

Here're some OpenAPI feature requests about non-schema $ref siblings that you can track/upvote:

- [Allow sibling elements with $ref that overrides the references definition](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/2744)
- [Allow required as sibling of $ref (like summary/description)](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/2498)
- [Extend/override properties of a parameter](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/2026)

#### OpenAPI 2.0 and 3.0.x

In these versions, `$ref` works by replacing itself and *all of its sibling elements* with the definition it is pointing at. That is why

```yaml
      lowerBound:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Time"
        description: Lower bound on the time interval.
        default: "00:00"
```

becomes

```yaml
      lowerBound:
        type: string
        description: Time in 24 hour format "hh:mm".
```

A possible workaround is to wrap `$ref` into `allOf` - this can be used to "add" attributes to a `$ref` but not override existing attributes.

```yaml
      lowerBound:
        allOf:
          - $ref: "#/definitions/Time"
        description: Lower bound on the time interval.
        default: "00:00"
```

Another way is to use replace the `$ref` with an inline definition.

```yaml
definitions:
  TimeInterval:
    type: object
    properties:
      lowerBound:
        type: string  # <------
        description: Lower bound on the time interval, using 24 hour format "hh:mm".
        default: "00:00"
      upperBound:
        type: string  # <------
        description: Upper bound on the time interval, using 24 hour format "hh:mm".
        default: "24:00"
```

Comment: If `TimeInterval` in this example is a class from which the swagger definition is generated -- the class might have Swagger Annotations too -- do you know how to code the class and/or annotations so that it generates either of the workarounds in this answer (i.e. using `allOf`, or using an inline definition instead of `$ref`)?

Comment: @ChrisW I don't know, sorry. Try [asking a new question](/questions/ask) about annotations.

Comment: Thank you. There already is such a question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57459520/49942)), I wondered if you just happened to know. I think I'll try to implement it by (instead of annotations) constructing a model instance for the class, and injecting that custom model instance via a ModelResolver.

Comment: @Helen,
Can you provide the official docs link of Open API stating the use of $ref along side the siblings is supported officially ?
As per official docs go for Open API [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/#sibling) use of siblings along side $ref is not supported.