# Swagger/Openapi-Annotations: How to produce allOf with $ref?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I'm generating Rest endpoints including adding **Openapi/Swagger** annotations to the generated code.

While it works quite well with basic types, I have some problems with custom classes.

Right now I have a lot of duplicate schema entries for the custom classes (using *@Schema(implementation = MyClass.class))* but at least the needed information is there. However I'd like to find a way to **remove the duplicate schema entries while retaining the additional information**.

On a github-issue discussing the **$ref** and lack of *sibling properties* I found [an example](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/556#issuecomment-192007034) how you would write it manually in yaml in order to get the result I'm looking for, however I can't figure out how to set the annotations to produce it.

This is how I *think* the annotation should look like if I follow the [example](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/556#issuecomment-192007034) (just to be on the safe side it is added to both the getter and the setter):

```
  import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;

  ...
public class SepaPaymentRequest {
  ...

  @Schema(name = "w307BetrBeg", description = "BETRAG BEGUENSTIGTER ", allOf = { com.diesoftware.services.utils.Betrag.class }, required = true)
  public void setW307BetrBeg(final Betrag w307BetrBeg) {
    this.w307BetrBeg = w307BetrBeg;
  }

  ...
}
```

However what I get when I fetch the openapi.yaml (snippet):

```
    w307BetrBeg:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Betrag'
```

What I'd like to have:

```
    w307BetrBeg:
      title: 'Betrag'
      description: 'BETRAG BEGUENSTIGTER'
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Betrag'
```

Any hints are more than welcome.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: Nothing so far, opened an [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3290) about a month ago. Also silence over there.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to do it using annotations, i.e. by annotating the class.

---

I think it's possible to do, by:

- Creating a model
- Injecting the model using a ModelConverter

When I say "a model" I mean an instance of `io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema`.

In particular I think you'd want to create and inject a `io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.ComposedSchema` instance, which supports `allOf`.

Doing this (i.e. creating model instances) isn't very different from hand-writing the YAML.

---

Another possibility -- which I haven't tried -- might be to write a slightly different ModelConverter, which you install into the chain of converters. Then, intercept calls to `resolve` which return a SchemaObject whose `name` is `Betrag`, and (sometimes?) replace that with a `ComposedSchema` instance which uses `allOf`.