# How do I reference the same schema as a property?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-editor

I have the following in my oas.yaml file:

```
components:
  schemas:
    ServiceError:
      type: object
      properties:
        Message:
          type: string
          description: "The exception message."
        ExceptionMessage:
          type: string
        Type:
          type: string
          description: "The exception type.""
        InnerError:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/ServiceError'
             description: "If there's an inner exception, the InnerException.

    Property:
      type: object
      properties:
        Name:
          type: string
          description: Name of the property.
```

It does not like the line "description: "If there's an inner exception, the InnerException." and if I remove that, it does not like the line "Property:". I've tried a lot of things and nothing works. What am I not understanding?

Comment: It doesn't like `InnerError.description` because there's no ending quote in it. And, as Martin said, there's an extra quote at the end of `Type.descritption`. You need to fix the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- a `description` is not allowed at the `$ref`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41752575/1262371).
- Before `InnnerError` are two '"'. Not sure if this is just a copy paste bug.

Comment: If no description is allowed, how do I get a comment for that property in the generated code? Thanks

Comment: The `ServiceError` itself can have a `description`.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41752575/1262371 shows a workaround using `allOf`.