# Swagger/OpenAPI ResponseBodies Parameter with Slight Variances

Tags: swagger, openapi

How can I change one part of the $ref, or add to it?

I have an OpenAPI 3.x response body:

```
ordernumber:
  $ref: '#/components/requestBodies/ordernumber'
```

The descriptive text is applicable to every instance I use this in, except for the last line. That changes for each product, like a product number.

There are similar questions but about schemas that don't seem to apply, neither do the anyof operators. I'd guess it should be like this, but of course, this doesn't work since no additional operation can be used with $ref.

```
ordernumber:
  $ref: '#/components/requestBodies/ordernumber'
  description: For all units number T100-T1200.
```

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [Schema properties ignored when using `$ref` - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33629750/113116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this doesn't work since no additional operation can be used with $ref.

Your example will work in OpenAPI 3.1 (new version released on February 16, 2021). OAS 3.1 supports having a `description` alongside `$ref`. In case of non-schema $refs, the adjacent `description` is supposed to [override the description](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.1.0.md#referenceObject) defined in the referenced component (if any).

Comment: Thanks. That was just lucky timing, it being added just two days before.