# Open API Spec V2.0 - Default value of a field of type Enum

Tags: spring-boot, enums, swagger, default, openapi-generator

I have a request body for an API specification in Swagger V2.0, which looks like follows.

```yaml
"/uri/path":
  ...
  parameters:
    - in: body
      ...
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/StatusObject'

definitions:
  StatusObject:
    status:
      $ref: '#/definitions/StatusEnum'

  StatusEnum:
    type: string
    enum: ['ALPHA', 'BRAVO', 'UNKNOWN']
```

Now, I want `StatusObject.status` to have the value `UNKNOWN` by default, if it is not set from the client end. I tried to achieve this as follows, with no luck.

```yaml
"/uri/path":
  ...
  parameters:
    - in: body
      ...
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/StatusObject'

definitions:
  StatusObject:
    status:
      $ref: '#/definitions/StatusEnum'
      default: 'UNKNOWN'

  StatusEnum:
    type: string
    enum: ['ALPHA', 'BRAVO', 'UNKNOWN']
```

I also have tried with `'#/definitions/StatusEnum.UNKNOWN'` which again didn't work. Combed through the documentation as well but couldn't find anything further. What am I missing?

### Response to marked duplicate

What I am trying to achieve is to set a default value for this property `status`. This works when the enum is defined in line as follows.

```yaml
"/uri/path":
  ...
  parameters:
    - in: body
      ...
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/StatusObject'

definitions:
  StatusObject:
    status:
      type: string
      enum:
        - 'ALPHA'
        - 'BRAVO'
        - 'UNKNOWN'
      default: 'UNKNOWN'
```

But, this won't work for me, as I'd like to reuse the enum, which otherwise I'll have to repeat at multiple places.

Comment: You need to wrap the `$ref` into `allOf`, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33629750/113116).

Comment: Thanks... I will leave this question on for reference purposes.

Comment: @Helen, I doubt if wrapping `$ref` in `allOf` works. Because I am still unable to enforce the default constraint. The default value of `status` of generated POJO is still null...

Comment: Could be an issue with the openapi-generator.

Comment: Yeah. Could be...

Answer (score 5):

Since this is just a workaround and I am not sure if I can confirm if this is an answer, I won't mark this as accepted answer. That way, I think it will be still open for someone who figured out the right way, or a better way to achieve the expectation.

Apparently, the problem is with `$ref`. It's already known that the siblings of `$ref` are ignored in OpenAPI V2.0. So, enforcing any further constraints once you use `$ref` won't be possible.

For my specific use case, since I want to reuse my enum definition, I used [YAML Anchors](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/enums/) as defined in V2.0 docs. Even though the enum definition is repeated in each POJO it's not that much of a headache to manage, at least for the time being. The implementation I came up is as follows.

```yaml
"/uri/path":
  ...
  parameters:
    - in: body
      ...
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/StatusObject'

definitions:
  StatusObject:
    status:
      enum: *STATUS_ENUM # Referencing the anchor
      default: 'UNKNOWN'

  StatusEnum:
    type: string
    enum: &STATUS_ENUM # This is the anchor
      - 'ALPHA'
      - 'BRAVO'
      - 'UNKNOWN'
```

It must also be noted that, the enum values in this case cannot be defined using array syntax (i.e. `['ALPHA', 'BRAVO', 'UNKNOWN']`) as it'll break the YAML syntax rules when you try to use YAML anchors alongside that.

Answer (score 0):

OpenAPI 3.1 supports `default` alongside `$ref`, e.g.

```yaml
  status:
    $ref: '#/definitions/StatusEnum'
    default: 'UNKNOWN'
```

With OpenAPI 3.0, you can use `allOf`, e.g.

```yaml
  status:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/StatusEnum'
      - default: 'UNKNOWN'
```