# How to make swagger examples component with allOf

Tags: swagger, openapi

```yaml
components:
 examples:
    J:
      value:
        name: my name
        
    J2:
      value:
        allOf: 
          - $ref: '#/components/examples/J'
          - id: 123
```

Use J2 in response body examples:

```yaml
responses:
  200:
    content:
      application/json:
        examples:
          test:
            $ref: '#/components/examples/J2'
```

Current result:

```json
{
  "$ref": "#/components/examples/J",
  "id": 123
}
```

Expected result

```json
{
  "name": "my name",
  "id": 123
}
```

Related:
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/

[Swagger schema properties ignored when using $ref - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629750/swagger-schema-properties-ignored-when-using-ref-why)

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported.

The `value` is meant to be the literal value of the example. As a result, `value` does not support `allOf` and `$ref`. OpenAPI does not have a way to merge the values of multiple example components.

Comment: So, I have to create another component for just add one element.

Comment: @ErtuğrulAltınboğa yes. Feel free to open an enhancement request in the OpenAPI Specification repository: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine at example level but you can combine examples at path level.

This is invalid

```
components:
 examples:
    J:
      value:
        name: my name
        
    J2:
      value:
        allOf: 
          - $ref: '#/components/examples/J'
          - id: 123
```

But you can do this

```
components:
 examples:
    J:
      value:
        name: my name
        
    J2:
      value:
        id: 123

content:
  application/json:
    schema:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyObject'
    examples:
      objectExample:
        allOf :
         - $ref: '#/components/examples/J'
         - $ref: '#/components/examples/J2'
```

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Nisha Dave response working with https://editor-next.swagger.io/

[image: snippet code]
[image: Result]

But there is a warning:

[image: Warning message]