# Swagger : nullable refs not in an array

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, openapi

I'm using Swagger and I want to get with annotations an API doc like that :

```
"myproperty":{
    "nullable": true,
    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MyProperty"
}
```

So I tried with :

```
  /**
   * @var MyProperty|null
   *
   * @OA\Schema(ref=@Model(type=MyProperty::class), nullable=true)
   */
  private $myproperty;
```

But when I generate my doc.json, I have :

```
"myproperty": {
            "nullable": true,
            "allOf": [
              {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Meta"
              }
            ]
          }
```

Having "$ref" in an array is an issue for me. How could I change that ?

Comment: Is the issue that the `$ref` points to the `Meta` schema instead of the `MyProperty` schema? Or do you mean some other issue?

Comment: Mistake in my copy-paste. It's myproperty. 
Actually, I don't want to have an "allOf". I saw I could change it in "oneOf" or "manyOf" but it's the same issue : with "nullable: true" it's inside an array.

Comment: The use of `allOf` is correct, it's the proper way to add keywords to a `$ref` in OAS 3.0.x and 2.0. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33629750/113116) for the explanation.