# OpenAPI 3.0 reuse enum values in different schemas

Tags: openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I have multiple request bodies that need to utilize the same enums, but am struggling to reference a single definition across multiple schemas.

Within my `openapi.yaml` file, I have included:

```
components:
  schemas:
    Widget:
      type: string
      enum:
        - THING
```

In the body definitions that I have for my POST/PUT requests, I include:

```
  widget:
    schema:
      $ref: '#/../openapi.yaml/components/schemas/Widget'
    description: Include Widgets in your API today!
```

but in the generated-code, what is being created is:

```
  @JsonProperty("widget")
  private Object widget; // expecting: `private Widget widget;`
```

while a separate class is created with:

```
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen")
public enum Widget {
  
  WIDGET("WIDGET"),
  
  private String value;

  Association(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @JsonValue
  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
...
```

How can I create a reference to enum definitions across files?

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is

```yaml
  widget:
    $ref: '../openapi.yaml#/components/schemas/Widget'
```

That is, you don't need the `schema` keyword inside property definitions. Also, `#` goes after the file name, not before it.

The file name (`../openapi.yaml`) is only needed if the schema is in a separate file. If the `Widget` schema is in the same file as your POST/PUT request definitions, you don't need the file name:

```yaml
  widget:
    $ref: '#/components/schemas/Widget'
```

If you want to provide a custom `description` alongside the `$ref`, you'll need to wrap the `$ref` into `allOf` (as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33629750/113116)):

```yaml
  widget:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Widget'
    description: Include Widgets in your API today!
```