# how to add an custom example to ApiResponse in nestjs

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I want to add some custom example to an ApiResponse.
I tried the following code but the output is the default:

```js
  @Get('/:id')
  @ApiResponse({
    status: HttpStatus.OK,
    type: ResponseDto,
  })
  @ApiResponse({
    description: 'Failure retrieving card details',
    status: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
    schema: {
      $ref: getSchemaPath(ErrorMessageDto),
      example: {
        errors: [
          {
            message: 'Invalid format',
            property: 'id',
            detail: null,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  })
  public async someMethod(): Promise<ResponseDto> {
    return ...
  }
```

[image: output]

I cannot put the example in ErrorMessageDto because will be used in all endpoints, and I want to put deferents examples in deferents endpoints.

[I know that swagger natively allows you to do this](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/).
how do it via nestjs?

Comment: It probably happens because you put the `example` alongside `$ref`, which causes the example to be ignored. You need to wrap the `$ref` into `allOf` as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41752575/113116).