# How to specify constants/enums for properties inside referenced properties in OpenAPI?

Tags: openapi

Is it some how possible to specify constants/enums for properties inside referenced complex properties in OpenAPI?

I know for a simple string property I can specify some enum constants which I expect/ allow (as you can see in the example below at property `sortOrder`.

As you can see in this example I define the `TestSearchModel` with the property `orderBy` which is of a referenced type `SortModel`. `SortModel` is actually defined in another file of a framework (PS: I have access and the permission to change that framework for my needs). In this `SortModel` there is the property `sortFieldName`. I wish I could specify in `TestSearchModel` that I only allow e.g. `ATTR_ONE`. Is that possible?

Maybe you can image my use case. I would like to define a search operation which expects an input of type `TestSearchModel`. With this input it should be possible to define a column/property by with the sorting of the results found should be done.

openapi.yaml:

```yaml
TestSearchModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    orderBy:
      $ref: "#/SortModel"
      enum: // allowed values of property sortFieldName in SortModel
        - ATTR_ONE
        - ATTR_TWO

SortModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    sortFieldName:
      type: string
    sortOrder:
      type: string
      enum:
        - ASC
        - DESC
```

This should be valid:

```json
{
  "orderBy": {
      "sortFieldName": "ATTR_ONE",
      "sortOrder": "ASC"
  }
}
```

This should end up in an error, because 'ATTR_THREE' is not defined above in the allowed values:

```json
  "sortModel": {
      "sortFieldName": "ATTR_THREE",
      "sortOrder": "ASC"
  }
```

I actually guess that with OpenAPI Spec this kind of specification is not possible. However may be you can provide some recommendations how to handle that.

I tried out the example above. OpenAPI generates the model classes without any error but (some kind of expected) without considering the limitation of the allowed strings for 'order by' property. I wish that an enum would be generated for ATTR_ONE and ATTR_TWO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is now:

```
TestSearchModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    orderBy:
      allOf:
        - $ref: "../../../../../src-gen/main/resources/openapi/model/base-search-model.yaml#/OrderByModel"
        - type: object
          properties:
            sortFieldName:
              enum:
                - name
                - geburtsdatum
                - justizbehoerde
                - modifikationszeit
```

where the file `base-search-model.yaml` is located in another maven artefact and we copy this file with maven into this project to src-gen/main/resources/openapi/model/base-search-model.yaml

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. You'll need to add an extra schema alongside the `$ref` that defines a property with the same name on the same nesting level.

If you use OpenAPI 3.0.x or 2.0, make sure to [wrap the `$ref` into `allOf`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33629750/113116):

```yaml
TestSearchModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    orderBy:
      allOf:
        - $ref: "#/SortModel"  # or "#/components/schemas/SortModel" or whatever the correct $ref path is

        - properties:          # <---
            sortFieldName:     # <---
              enum:
                - ATTR_ONE
                - ATTR_TWO

SortModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    sortFieldName:
      type: string
    sortOrder:
      type: string
      enum:
        - ASC
        - DESC
```

In OpenAPI 3.1, you can add keywords directly alongside the `$ref`:

```yaml
# openapi: 3.1.0

TestSearchModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    orderBy:
      $ref: "#/SortModel"  # or "#/components/schemas/SortModel" or whatever the correct $ref path is
      properties:          # <---
        sortFieldName:     # <---
          enum:
            - ATTR_ONE
            - ATTR_TWO
```

Comment: Thanks your for the reply.

As I use OpenAPI verion 3.0.1 I tried your first suggestion. But in this case class TestSearchModel is generated with the property sortModel which is of new generated type 'TestSearchModelSortModel' but it should be of type SortModel. Any hints on that?
I will try to upgrade to OpenAPI 3.1.0 later this week.

Comment: I think the only way to have the `sortModel` property be of type `SortModel` is to move the enum directly into the `SortModel` schema, as in @skidwiz's answer. But when using `allOf` + `$ref` to extend a schema, you're literally defining a new schema, which is reflected accordingly in the generated code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your schema above is that openapi won't read anything after the `$ref` field.  So, the enum value you have placed there is ignored. You can move the enum to your SortModel and it will be available:

```yaml
TestSearchModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    orderBy:
      $ref: "#/SortModel"

SortModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    sortFieldName:
      type: string
      enum:
        - ATTR_ONE
        - ATTR_TWO
    sortOrder:
      type: string
      enum:
        - ASC
        - DESC
```

If you are trying to reuse the enum, you can do this via a reference, like this

```yaml
TestSearchModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    orderBy:
      $ref: "#/SortFields"
SortModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    sortFieldName:
      $ref: "#/SortFields"
    sortOrder:
      $ref: "#/SortOrderTypes"
SortOrderTypes:
  type: string
  enum:
    - ASC
    - DESC
SortFields:
  type: string
  enum:
    - ATTR_ONE
    - ATTR_TWO
```